# Excel 2013 Pivot Chart: wrong day-count on y-axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-chart, axis

I'm making this pivot-chart where the orange series shows the average count of days (gg) with hh:mm:ss part.

Now, as you can see on the picture the pop-up shows the correct value (00gg 23:53:37), but the y-axis and the orange label don't. I really don't understand why the y-axes starts from 30 days instead 0.
The series is a normal line (not stacked).

One more information, the value is a decimal with the SSAS format_string 'dd"gg" hh:mm:ss'.

I'm using Excel 2013.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the orange line is on the secondary axis. Access the secondary axis properties and you will find a min value that you can change to get it to zero.

Comment: I did a test on Excel 365 and I had the same result, the label and data on Y-axis start from "30" not "00". I think "dd" of the custom format means the date, not the count of days, and the month starts from 01, not 00.